# Rotating player movement with camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a physics based ball game and I'm having issues moving the camera and allowing the player to move relative to where the camera is. Rotating the player does not work as the player rotates due to it being a physics object, so any ideas on how to implement this? The player movement uses the addforce function for rigidbodies.

Comment: Your question is too vague to receive a meaningful/useful answer.

Comment: intead of parenting the camera, you can update its position/rotation in Update, where you can put your own logic regarding how to move/rotate it (parenting is quite inflexible)